# using %s, %d to assign pass/fail to grade determination based on user input score (python)

Tags: python

desired outcome:
Enter a test score (-99 to exit): 55
Enter a test score (-99 to exit): 77
Enter a test score (-99 to exit): 88
Enter a test score (-99 to exit): 24
Enter a test score (-99 to exit): 45
Enter a test score (-99 to exit): -99
55 77 88 24 45 
P  P  P  F  F

Process finished with exit code 0

The code so far: (works except for Pass fail assignment)

Python Program to ask user to input scores that are added to a list called scores. Then prints under that score P for Pass F for fail.

```
scores = [] #list is initialized

while True:
    score = int(input("Enter a test score (-99 to exit): "))
    if score == -99:
        break
    scores.append(score)

def print_scores(): #accepts the list and prints each score separated by a space
    for item in scores:
        print(item, end = " ")      # or 'print item,'
print_scores()       # print output

def set_grades():       #function determines whether pass or fail
    for grade in scores:
        if score >= 50:
            print("P")
        else:
            print("F")
print(set_grades)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to illustrate the exact output you expect, and how it currently looks like? Furthermore, your `print_scores` says that it *accepts a list* but it does not. It happens to use the globally scoped `scores` list you created, but if you in fact want your `print_scores` to take a list, then you need to make sure your function actually takes a list as an argument -> `def print_scores(the_list):`

Comment: #this is the desired outcome:.....                                                            
Enter a test score (-99 to exit): 55
Enter a test score (-99 to exit): 77
Enter a test score (-99 to exit): 49
Enter a test score (-99 to exit): -99
55 77 49
P   P   F
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Edit your question to put that in there and format it properly. Setting that as a comment does not translate well.

Comment: does that help? basically the P or F (pass or fail) right under the score.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking along the right lines, but you need to run through your program from the top and make sure that you're getting your reasoning right.

Firstly, you've written the program to print out all the scores before you get to checking if they're passes, so you'll get a list of numbers and then a list of P/F. These need to happen together to display properly. 
Also, make sure that you keep track of what variable is what; in your last function, you attempt to use 'score', which doesn't exist anymore.
Finally, I'm not sure what exactly you're asking with %d or %s, but you may be looking for named arguments with `format()`, which are shown below.

```
scores = [] #list is initialized

while True:
    score = int(input("Enter a test score (-99 to exit): "))
    if score == -99:
        break
    scores.append(score)

for item in scores:
    if item >= 50:
        mark = 'P'
    else:
        mark = 'F'

    print('{0} {1}'.format(item, mark))
```

I believe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you for that . the {} parameter is something new to me. how do i format it to get the P F to be under the grade? the current formating has changed it to list the grades vertically now.

Comment: i know [] bracket notation to be reference to dictionary notation. i am learning more from stackoverflow and youtube than i am from this online community college

Comment: To put the P/F under the grade, change the string from '{0} {1}' to '{0}\n{1}'.

Comment: great thank you. i put the new line indent after and got problems. thanks all for the help. i am learning a lot!

Comment: The formatting using {} is used inside a string, and if you then use the format() function on that string it will replace it. So {0} will be replaced by the first argument in format(), which is 'item' in this case. The backslash is called an 'escape' character, and the character that follows it will represent something you can't normally type. \n gives you a newline, which is the most useful one.

Comment: its nice to have pycharm tell you where you went wrong. but for someone with no prior programming background, having to associate %d and %s with representational parameters for strings vs. numbers is confusing. Programming really is a language like any other. I am finding even though with coding logic of arguments is structured line by line , it does jump around sometimes. i suppose like everything else the more time you spend the more second nature it gets.